# React Hook not able to use new state in the same function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook im using. Im setting the state to +1 . I see it does change correctly in the DOM if i place the eqNum variable in my html. the problem is with the new state of the variable I need to use it to create my object. The object ends up using the eqNum s previous state of 1 instead of 2. Any way I can get around this issue???

```
const [eqNum, setEqNum] = useState(1) ;

const handleAddNewEq = () => {
    const fieldset = document.getElementById("fieldset" + eqNum);
    console.log("this is eqNum", eqNum, "this is fieldset", fieldset)
    fieldset.disabled = true;

    setEqNum( eqNum + 1);

    console.log(eqNum)

    const equipment = {
        divEq:"divEq" + eqNum,
        formEq:"formEq" + eqNum,
        warrantyDtlDiv:"warrantyDetail" + eqNum,
        warrantyCheckbox:"warrantyCheckbox"+eqNum,
        fieldset:"fieldset" + eqNum,
        eqNum: "eqNum" + eqNum,
        brand:"",
        model:"",
        serialnumber:"",
        type:"",
        problemdesc:"",
        warrantycompany:"",
        datepurchased:"",
        warrantynotes:""
    };

    setEquipments([...equipments, equipment]);

    console.log("new equipment array", equipments)
};
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous so you can't use or print them on the next line. Within the just store the incremented value in a variable and use that instead of `eq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
const [eqNum, setEqNum] = useState(1) ;

const handleAddNewEq = () => {
    const fieldset = document.getElementById("fieldset" + eqNum);
    console.log("this is eqNum", eqNum, "this is fieldset", fieldset)
    fieldset.disabled = true;

    setEqNum( eqNum + 1);

};

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(eqNum)

    const equipment = {
        divEq:"divEq" + eq,
        formEq:"formEq" + eq,
        warrantyDtlDiv:"warrantyDetail" + eq,
        warrantyCheckbox:"warrantyCheckbox"+eq,
        fieldset:"fieldset" + eq,
        eqNum: "eqNum" + eq,
        brand:"",
        model:"",
        serialnumber:"",
        type:"",
        problemdesc:"",
        warrantycompany:"",
        datepurchased:"",
        warrantynotes:""
    };

    setEquipments([...equipments, equipment]);

    console.log("new equipment array", equipments)
}, [eqNum]);
```

use effect will trigger every time the `eqNum` value changed.